# Where's the CSS for the Jammy Jellyfish task switcher

Tags: gnome, themes

The default app switcher on my Jammy Jellyfish system does everything I want functionally but the cosmetics need tweaking. I've been trying to get to the CSS to improve the contrast of the travelling highlight, which is currently barely visible.

Gnome-tweaks allows me to change some features of the appearance. But not, apparently, the app switcher. I've been delving for the CSS down in `/usr/share/themes` but haven't come up with anything useful. I haven't been able to find any help for this on the Web either.

I have this Ubuntu set to Xorg but Wayland offers no improvement on this issue. Help would be very welcome.

11 DAYS LATER

Does the fact that there's been no response mean that no-one else has this problem with the app switcher? Or that the solution is so simple it scarcely needs mentioning. Or that nobody is actually using Jammy Jellyfish?

Any ideas on where else I should be posting this question would be very welcome.

--

Chris

[image: the barely visible travelling highlight is on item 2]

Comment: No, it means that it's not controlled by a "CSS".

Comment: That thought had crossed my mind, @waltinator. But are we saying that this non-contrast travelling highlight is hardwired into gnome-shell 42? Why would the devs do that?

Actually, my conjecture about CSS isn't embedded in my second post. Whether the colour scheme is CSS-controlled or not, is it really the case that no-one else is having problems with this. Are you happy with the app-switcher, @waltinator?

Answer (score 0):

OK, we have a workaround for this.

The app switcher by default has a travelling highlight that is barely distinguishable from the background. There is probably some CSS somewhere that will fix this, but I was unable to find it and I could elicit no help from the Web.

Installing the **Just Perfection gnome-shell extension** didn’t seem to be much help either. I found it hard to determine whether using the Override Shell Theme switch found in Just Perfection’s Profile/Custom tab made any improvement—possibly this produces a very slight increase in contrast between the travelling highlight and the background.

[image: Just Perfection Override Switch]

However, Just Perfection has its own, easily located CSS in its directory under `~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions`. In its `stylesheet.css` is this section:

```
.just-perfection .switcher-list .item-box:selected
{
background-color: #404040;
color: #eeeeec;
}
```

I don’t understand much of what’s going on here, except to have discovered by experiment that `background-color` actually means the colour of the travelling highlight. Change this to something lighter (I chose `silver`), restart gnome-shell (Alt-F2 and "r"), and the app switcher lights up very nicely.

--

Chris